# Qt/PyQt: How do I manually draw a caret?

Tags: qt, pyqt, paint

I know a position within a QWidget where I would like to draw a caret.

1. Calling paint redraws the entire widget, and I only want to redraw that one 'box' containing the caret/character. Is there a way to tell it not to erase the entire widget?
2. How do I create a timer that will cause it to blink (even when the program is doing something else)?

I am looking to do it manually, not through QTextLayout.

Comment: This begs the question: "Why?". What is it you're trying to achieve that would mean you need to manually do something like that?

Comment: I'm trying to program a custom text renderer/editor for an ebook editing program. QTextEdit is to slow for loading/editing large richtext documents. QWebKit sometimes has extremely slow wysiwyg editing. QTextLayout does not allow for images. So, considering that I am using only a subset of html and more or less understand the theory of rendering, I am writing my own custom one (I already have the pseudo code).

Comment: Ah well, I guess I'll just have to read through the source code for QTextedit and its called subclasses and so on....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QWidget has a repaint() method to repaint only a certain portion of the widget

```
QWidget.repaint (self, int x, int y, int w, int h)
QWidget.repaint (self, QRect)
QWidget.repaint (self, QRegion)
```

You can create a QTimer that will fire at intervals:

```
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(doBlinkMethod)
timer.start(1000) # every second

def doBlinkMethod():
    print "blah"
```

You could also implement your widgets own built in timer to just act on itself internally:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#startTimer

Comment: Clear, succinct, and usefull. Thanks!